# How do I force user to enter specific pattern in input field using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I admit, I never explored into the regex albeit knowing its power. And its striking back to me.
I am trying to make user enter pattern P99999999 into an input text where P is mandatory while 99999999 can take any digits(not letters). I'm triggering keyup, input field has uppercasing through styling and so far, this is what I have done (I know its too little).

```
inpt.value = $.trim( inpt.value );
if( inpt.value.indexOf( 'P' ) != 0 )
    inpt.value = inpt.value.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '');
```

After some exploring I come up with this

```
[P]+[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?
```

I do not know how to validate my input against this. This was generated by an online tool. I know it shouldn't be that hard. Any help.

Comment: Just remember that you still have to validate the input server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[updated to fix the stream input (hold key) issue]**

here you go

regex [ it might look unconventional as there can be none (*) digits but think again, it is a live validation not the final result validation ]:

```
^P\d*$
```

code [edit: **simplified**]:

```
    $('input').on('change keyup keydown',function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(/^P\d*$/.test(txt)&txt.length<10?txt:txt.substring(0,txt.length-1));
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/rnrX9/3/)

Comment: I thought you wanted a captial P only :) .. it is good that it helped

Comment: how to format a date format dd/MM/YYYY ? I tried the same code with this pattern  /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([1][26]|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g  but it doesnt work

Comment: @andQlimax sorry for the late reply. wow what is that? this regex should be much simpler, it's an unrelated to the question but I'll help you out: `^(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}$`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
P[0-9]{8}
```

That's a P, and then any number eight times.

If a P followed by any number of digits is valid, try

```
P[0-9]+
```

That's a P, and then any number at least once.

To make sure that this is all they enter, add ^ and $ (as mentioned in the comments):

```
^P[0-9]+$
```

A ^ is 'start of input', and the $ is 'end of input'.

So, your final code might be something like:

```
<input type="text" />
<div class="fail" style="display: none;">Fail!</div>
```

and

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var patt=/^P[0-9]+$/g;
    var result=patt.test($(this).val());
    if (result) {
        $(".fail").hide();        
    } else {
        $(".fail").show();        
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuMg4/1/

Finally, make sure you check this on the server side as well. It's easy to bypass client-side validation.

This tool is pretty handy: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: You need ^ and $ to anchor the content, otherwise PPPPP00000000000000 is legal.

Comment: True, true. I'll add a third example.

Comment: Also, OP asked how to validate against the input

Comment: this won't be valid until you input the P and a digit character together at the first event , you have to account for the P alone ,, use * in place of + like I did

Comment: But that makes an input of "P" valid, which (I assume) is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a third party plugin, like [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)...

Requirements like this have been implemented ad nauseum in javascript. You're trying to recreate the wheel, yet again.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes! But, this is a part of a component which I really do not want to make dependent on anything else than jQuery. True, it will save time if I use mask but for a puny little thing like this, I feel like some home brewing is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *pattern* attribute

http://cssdeck.com/labs/n8h33j1w

```
<input type="text" required pattern="^P[0-9]+$" />

input:invalid {
  background: red;
}

input:valid {
  background: green;
}
```

Be aware that older browsers will need a polyfill (namely, IE), as this is a relatively new property.