# How to restrict set of allowed characters in input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I know that this question has been asked before, but all solutions that I've seen here had some limitations.

What I'm trying to achieve: I have an input field that should allow entering or pasting only alphanumeric characters, and total length must not exceed N characters. It should work in mobile browsers.

What I have tried so far:

1. *input* event. Triggered only when the focus is lost.
2. *onkeypress* event (`return this.value.length < 8 && (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 || event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122 || event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)`). Doesn't affect pasting and for some strange reason doesn't work at all in Chrome on Android.
3. *pattern* attribute. Works fine, but doesn't validate anything "on the fly" - all validation happens when the form is submitted.

As far as I know, it is a typical task (CVV codes / card numbers on payment forms, order numbers in e-commerce, etc.), but all solutions have some drawbacks. Seems that I am missing something. Please help.

Comment: As usual, use `oninput` event instead of keyevents. `input` event surely fires on every change on the input element, it is `onchange` which fires only when the focus is lost.

Comment: Thanks! But how to restrict the character set in `oninput` event? I've tried `this.value = this.value.substring(0, 8).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')`, but when user inserts something in the middle, cursor is moved to the end of the input control.

Comment: Well, what you seem to be doing currently is replace the value at every input change, even when that is not necessary! What you could do instead to prevent the cursor from being moved to the end is test whether the new text violates some conditions (in this case if it is longer than 8 characters or if it contains characters other than ranges a-z, A-Z and 0-9) and only update the value in that case.

Comment: How can I prevent the value from updating in `oninput` event?

Answer (score 10):

What about using [Input Pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)?

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letters">
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="Three numbers">    
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}" title="Three alphanumeric">
```

combined with something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303169/2938073)
and [this](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/)

Comment: Note that this applies when the form is submitted, it does not limit the characters that can be entered into the field prior to submission.

Comment: You're right. But IMHO, there's a reason it implemented that way, and forcing otherwise can lead to frustrating UX

Answer (score 0):

I once needed to do the same thing and I found that the best solution is to have a listener that is called every time the input field changes. For this you should be able to use either the `oninput` html attribute or the corresponding `input` javascript event.

[This demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oninput) from W3Schools demonstrates pretty well how it responds to input changes. In particular, it does not only fire when focus is lost and it works when pasting text as well. Naturally, inside the listener you can check that the current text in the input conforms to whatever you want.

What's even cooler with this solution is that you can even edit the text inside the input field from within the listener. For this you need to add the listener to the `input` event in javascript using `addEventListener(...)`, then just use `this.value = 'new text';`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the validation built into Html5 inputs will prevent non-numeric input when you place the type=number attribute to an input. You could also use the max attribute if you want to set a maximum number to be allowed for entry. You still need to implement some type of client-side code to prevent numbers with older browsers, but the basic Html5 validation does a lot o work for you on any decent "real" browser (Chrome, Firefox, I.E v9+, ect)

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) is documentation on the input type="number"

- elements automatically invalidate any entry
  that isn't a number (or empty, unless required is specified).
- You can use the required attribute to make an empty entry invalid,
  i.e. the input has to be filled in.
- You can use the step attribute to constrain valid values to a certain
  set of steps (e.g. multiples of 10).
- You can use the min and max attributes to constrain valid values to
  lower and upper bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `type=numeric` doesn't fit my needs because I need alphanumeric input. `required` attribute affect form submit, not the input.